# Unable to call CodeIgniter controller function from command line

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I'm writing a cron job function and my project is built upon `CodeIgniter framework`. Following is my controller class (`Cron.php`) present in my authentication server.

```
class Cron extends CI_Controller {

    public function log_update() {

        $opts = array('http' =>
          array(
              'method' => 'GET',
              'timeout' => 10
          )
      );
      $context = stream_context_create($opts);

      $url = "http://lamp.co.uk/project/data_controller/get_log_update";

        $contents = file_get_contents($url, TRUE, $context);

      var_dump($contents);
    }
 }
```

And following is my `Data_controller` class present in my project server.

```
class Data_controller extends MY_Controller {

public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  echo "hi ";
}

public function get_log_update() {
  echo "welcome";
}
```

}

When I executed `php index.php cron log_update` from auth server command line, only the string "hi" gets displayed instead of "hi welcome".

But it works when I call `$this->get_log_update()` inside the Data_controller constructor and also when I directly access the url from the browser

Have I done anything silly or is there a bigger problem.

Comment: what about if  u try to get it from browser address bar ?

Comment: @siddhesh Sorry, I get only "hi" when access the url from the browser bar.

Comment: Why does Data_controller extend from MY_Controller, but the controller that works extends from CI_Controller?

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with a CLI issue.

First see what happens if you use `php-cli index.php cron log_update` instead of `php index.php cron get_log_update()` (just add **-cli**).

Then if that doesn't work, try wrapping your `echo` on a `if (is_cli())` statement and see what happens.  Actually, try `echo "inside cli"` and another `echo "not cli"` on an *else* to that *if* in order to get more hints on what's going on.

Please let me know if this helped.

EDIT here is a working example with is_cli:

```
class Rutinas extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    // html y url autoloaded

    if (is_cli()) {
        $this->load->model('Trips_model');
        echo "ejecutando cronjob...\r\n";
     } else {
        echo "creo que has perdido el camino...";
     }
}

//redirect if needed, otherwise display the user list
function index()
{
    if (is_cli())
     {
        $viajes_por_archivar = $this->Trips_model->trips_to_update();
        echo "Viajes archivados:\t".$update_past_trips_result;
        echo "\r\n";
        echo "Acuerdos archivados:\t".$update_lost_deals_result;
     } else {
        echo " en el index";
        // $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
        // phpinfo();
     }
}
}
```

Comment: `php-cli` didn't work and when tried `is_cli()` there was a fatal error "undefined function". I replaced it with `is_cli_request()` as per google which also resulted in the same error. Then I found `$this->input->is_cli_request()` which is specific to CodeIgniter and it echoes "inside cli". At last I executed with `php -cli` and it worked but displayed only "hi" instead of "hi welcome".

Comment: This is the right track.  Could you post your entire code with $this->input->is_cli_request() and also your latest cron instruction?  Also, make sure you are using the full path to php-cli.

Comment: @DhiwaTdG is just added an example to my answer. I hope this works as a reference.  Feel free to post your code so I can go over it.

Comment: @DhiwaTdG I was just wondering if you manage to solve this using my example